# Spark SVG renderening options in Flex?

Tags: flash, apache-flex, graphics, svg

I am a bit new to vectors so bear with me. 
What I am trying to do is make a toolbar in Flex from some vector graphics I have created in Illustrator.

The problem is when I import the vectors into Flex as an SVG some scaling(?) seems to occur, pixelating my once crisp vector.

Initially I thought the problem was because my graphics were small (32 x 32) so I tried hard coding one directly into my Flex mxml file and it looks great.  Here's a [comparison](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/56138370/svgvshardcoded.png) :

[image]

Obviously hardcoding in not a great solution, besides which I had intended to have the vectors within Spark images because I need tooltip functionality.

This is [the SVG file](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/56138370/zoomout.svg) I am using :

```
<!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 16.0.0, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 0)  -->
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
     width="32.469px" height="33.625px" viewBox="0 0 32.469 33.625" enable-background="new 0 0 32.469 33.625" xml:space="preserve">
<g id="New_Symbol_2">
    <g>

            <radialGradient id="SVGID_1_" cx="294.9609" cy="-374.6421" r="13.4597" gradientTransform="matrix(1 0 0 -1 -281.5 -360.8696)" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
            <stop  offset="0.8966" style="stop-color:#DDDDDD"/>
            <stop  offset="1" style="stop-color:#AAAAAA"/>
        </radialGradient>
        <path fill="url(#SVGID_1_)" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="0.25" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M25.18,20.525
            c1.104-1.996,1.741-4.298,1.741-6.752C26.921,6.178,20.882,0,13.46,0C6.039,0,0,6.178,0,13.772c0,7.594,6.039,13.774,13.46,13.774
            c2.777,0,5.358-0.866,7.503-2.345l0.081,0.083l4.269-4.623L25.18,20.525z M13.46,23.309c-5.138,0-9.319-4.277-9.319-9.536
            c0-5.257,4.181-9.534,9.319-9.534c5.142,0,9.319,4.277,9.319,9.534C22.779,19.031,18.602,23.309,13.46,23.309z"/>

            <linearGradient id="SVGID_2_" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="306.4043" y1="-399.7759" x2="310.9532" y2="-394.8978" gradientTransform="matrix(1 0 0 -1 -281.5 -370.375)">
            <stop  offset="0.1576" style="stop-color:#DDDDDD"/>
            <stop  offset="0.468" style="stop-color:#000000"/>
        </linearGradient>
        <path fill="url(#SVGID_2_)" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="0.25" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M31.091,26.574l-5.778-5.913
            l-4.268,4.623l5.653,5.786C27.305,31.689,28.1,32,28.895,32s1.59-0.311,2.196-0.93C32.303,29.828,32.303,27.816,31.091,26.574z"/>

            <linearGradient id="SVGID_3_" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="289.209" y1="-384.147" x2="301.6338" y2="-384.147" gradientTransform="matrix(1 0 0 -1 -281.5 -370.375)">
            <stop  offset="0.2808" style="stop-color:#0080FF"/>
            <stop  offset="1" style="stop-color:#0013FF"/>
        </linearGradient>

            <rect x="7.709" y="11.653" fill="url(#SVGID_3_)" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="0.25" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="12.425" height="4.238"/>

            <linearGradient id="SVGID_4_" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="285.6406" y1="-384.1484" x2="304.2793" y2="-384.1484" gradientTransform="matrix(1 0 0 -1 -281.5 -370.375)">
            <stop  offset="0" style="stop-color:#FFFFFF"/>
            <stop  offset="1" style="stop-color:#8FD9F9"/>
        </linearGradient>
        <path fill="url(#SVGID_4_)" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="0.25" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M13.46,4.238
            c-5.138,0-9.319,4.277-9.319,9.534c0,5.257,4.181,9.537,9.319,9.537c5.142,0,9.319-4.279,9.319-9.537
            C22.779,8.515,18.602,4.238,13.46,4.238z M7.709,15.891v-4.238h12.425v4.238H7.709z"/>
    </g>
</g>
</svg>
```

Here's the Flex code :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
               xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"
               minWidth="955" minHeight="600">

    <!--toolbar background-->
    <s:Rect id="background" width="45" height="400">
        <s:stroke>
            <s:SolidColorStroke color="0x000000" weight="1"/>
        </s:stroke>
        <s:fill>
            <s:LinearGradient>
                <s:entries>
                    <s:GradientEntry alpha="0.1" color="0x3366FF" ratio="0.33"/>
                    <s:GradientEntry alpha="0.1" color="0x0066ff" ratio="0.66"/>
                </s:entries>
            </s:LinearGradient>
        </s:fill>
    </s:Rect>

    <!--icons-->
    <s:HGroup width="100%" height="100%" gap="0">
        <s:VGroup height="100%" gap="10" paddingBottom="5" paddingLeft="5" paddingRight="5"
                  paddingTop="5">

            <!--imported svg-->
            <s:Image id="zoomoutButton" source="@Embed(source='../images/zoomout.svg')"
                     toolTip="Zoom out"/>

            <!--same image hardcoded-->
            <s:Group>
                <s:Path x="0.125" y="0.125"
                        data="M25.1797 20.5254C26.2842 18.5293 26.9209 16.2271 26.9209 13.7729 26.9209 6.17822 20.8818 0 13.46 0 6.03906 0 0 6.17822 0 13.772 0 21.3662 6.03906 27.5459 13.46 27.5459 16.2368 27.5459 18.8184 26.6797 20.9629 25.2012L21.0439 25.2842 25.3125 20.6611       25.1797 20.5254ZM13.46 23.3086C8.32178 23.3086 4.14111 19.0312 4.14111 13.7729 4.14111 8.51611 8.32178 4.23926 13.46 4.23926 18.6016 4.23926 22.7793 8.51611 22.7793 13.7729 22.7793 19.0312 18.6016 23.3086 13.46 23.3086Z"
                        winding="nonZero">
                    <s:fill>
                        <s:RadialGradient x="13.4609" y="13.7725" scaleX="26.9194" scaleY="-26.9194">
                            <s:GradientEntry color="#DDDDDD" ratio="0.8966"/>
                            <s:GradientEntry color="#AAAAAA" ratio="1"/>
                        </s:RadialGradient>
                    </s:fill>
                    <s:stroke>
                        <s:SolidColorStroke caps="none" joints="miter" miterLimit="10" weight="0.25"/>
                    </s:stroke>
                </s:Path>
                <s:Path x="21.1699" y="20.7861"
                        data="M10.0459 5.91309 4.26758 0 0 4.62305 5.65332 10.4092C6.25977 11.0283 7.05469 11.3389 7.84961 11.3389 8.64453 11.3389 9.43945 11.0283 10.0459 10.4092 11.2578 9.16699 11.2578 7.15527 10.0459 5.91309Z"
                        winding="nonZero">
                    <s:fill>
                        <s:LinearGradient x="3.85938" y="8.73975" rotation="312.999" scaleX="6.67011">
                            <s:GradientEntry color="#DDDDDD" ratio="0.1576"/>
                            <s:GradientEntry ratio="0.468"/>
                        </s:LinearGradient>
                    </s:fill>
                    <s:stroke>
                        <s:SolidColorStroke caps="none" joints="miter" miterLimit="10" weight="0.25"/>
                    </s:stroke>
                </s:Path>
                <s:Rect x="7.83398" y="11.7778" width="12.4248" height="4.23828">
                    <s:fill>
                        <s:LinearGradient x="0" y="2.11914" scaleX="12.4248">
                            <s:GradientEntry color="#0080FF" ratio="0.2808"/>
                            <s:GradientEntry color="#0013FF" ratio="1"/>
                        </s:LinearGradient>
                    </s:fill>
                    <s:stroke>
                        <s:SolidColorStroke caps="none" joints="miter" miterLimit="10" weight="0.25"/>
                    </s:stroke>
                </s:Rect>
                <s:Path x="4.26611" y="4.36279"
                        data="M9.31885 0C4.18066 0 0 4.27734 0 9.53418 0 14.7915 4.18066 19.0708 9.31885 19.0708 14.4604 19.0708 18.6382 14.7915 18.6382 9.53418 18.6382 4.27734 14.4604 0 9.31885 0ZM3.56787 11.6533 3.56787 7.41504 15.9927 7.41504 15.9927 11.6533 3.56787 11.6533Z"
                        winding="nonZero">
                    <s:fill>
                        <s:LinearGradient x="-0.000488281" y="9.53564" scaleX="18.6387">
                            <s:GradientEntry color="#FFFFFF" ratio="0"/>
                            <s:GradientEntry color="#8FD9F9" ratio="1"/>
                        </s:LinearGradient>
                    </s:fill>
                    <s:stroke>
                        <s:SolidColorStroke caps="none" joints="miter" miterLimit="10" weight="0.25"/>
                    </s:stroke>
                </s:Path>
            </s:Group>
        </s:VGroup>
    </s:HGroup>


</s:Application>
```

Would really appreciate any help / pointers as to how to get this working properly.

Using Flex 4.6.0 by the way.

Thanks!

Frankie

Comment: Any particular reason you're using svg instead of fxg format?

Comment: it seemed a little more straight forward to start with, I did try adding it as an fxg to a button icon but I had the exact same issue...

Comment: What is the difference between the SVG you hard coded and the one you generated from Illustrator?

Comment: I got the code for the hard coded version by saving my graphic in illustrator as an fxg then copying the code from that and adding namespaces to the tags. They were generated in different ways.

Comment: You said one version works and the other doesn't so what is the difference between the two?  Figuring that out most likely contains the solution to your problem.

Comment: it is a bit of an odd one, I can embed the fxg as a spark bitmap image and it suffers from the same issue as the svg.  This leads me to suspect it is the way flex is dealing with rendering the file contents as opposed to the vector itself.  Saying that though there is a good chance I am mis-using illustrator too.

Comment: Aha, but you don't have to use an FXG as the source of a BitmapImage. You can insert the FXG file as an mxml tag just like any other component, as long as it's on the source path.

Answer (score 1):

I notice that your SVG file specifies hard-coded height and width in the SVG node itself:

```
... width="32.469px" height="33.625px" viewBox="0 0 32.469 33.625" ...
```

but in your "hard-coded" version, that node obviously isn't there. Could that be the difference? If Flex rasterizes the vector drawing to be exactly 33.625px high, and then the `<s:Image/>` is a slightly different size in the display list, it might try to scale it as a bitmap, which sort of defeats the whole purpose of vector graphics.

Does it get better if you just drop those size attributes?

Comment: I'm unclear how you determined the width/height attributes were not there in the "hard-coded" version.  As best I can tell the question only provides a single file.

Comment: if I remove the height and width from the svg node and then run the graphic is much bigger but perfectly rendered. I then tried adding width and height from the svg to the s:Image in the mxml file and it renders much better.  Not perfect but much better.  It looks like I need to find the perfect width / height combo in order to get this to display correctly as the one from the svg still cause scaling.  Thanks for the answer - I think we're on the right track :)

Comment: Yeah, make it the height and width you want using controls on the s:Image, that way, it scales with vectors, not pixels. I would also suggest that you round off to whole numbers of pixels. Things tend to look better in Flex when you avoid fractional pixels. Not perfect, you say? Is it still blurry?

Comment: yes, still blurry sadly.  Only a little but still...  I have exported the graphics as pngs for now which display a lot more sharply.