# embedding svg file in air as3 in flash builder 4.7

Tags: actionscript-3, svg, air, flash-builder

SVG file is version 1.0 exported from Adobe Illustrator 18.1.1, I have air sdk 17.0 and I tried it with adobe flex sdk 4.6.0 as well as apache flex sdk 4.14.0 included in flash builder premium 4.7 and I still get this error:
*File ... is of an unknown file type which can't be embedded*

if i set the mime-type to *application/octet-stream*, error goes away but it seems i cant work with it as a Sprite..
code I use for embedding:

```
[Embed(source="../assets/Score.svg", mimeType="image/svg-xml")]
[Bindable] 
public var BonusScore:Class;
```

tried even without *[Bindable]* tag..

with mimeType *image/svg* is it the same situation..

Do you know how to get it working? Do you have the same experience?

Comment: The mime type for SVG is image/svg+xml, not image/svg

Comment: possible duplicate of [Spark SVG renderening options in Flex?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17568559/spark-svg-renderening-options-in-flex)

Comment: check if the svg has flowRoots. I could not get this to work if there are flowroots in the svg. Once I removed them and saved it as a "plain SVG" in Inkscape, it worked (you can use the xml editor in Inkscape to remove these tags)

Answer (score -1):

Though this question is old. But if anyone comes to this thread (like me) hoping for a solution, here is how it worked for me:

```
[Embed(source="funny.svg", mimeType="application/octet-stream")]
private static const funny:Class;`
```